# SEAb shows conflicting results from SEA and SEAc

Tags: r, function, bayesian, ellipse, jquery-isotope

So I am using SIBER to compare the isotopic niche areas of 4 species, and want to make comparisons between species 1 and 2, and 3 and 4. In my isotopic niche plot, species 1 and 2 are roughly the same area, whereas 3 is visibly smaller than 4 in area.  SEA and SEAc also reflect the differences in size of the graph:

```
    SEA      SEAc       TA
[1,] 0.7205109 0.7655428 2.261943
[2,] 0.7808720 0.7886034 4.290660
[3,] 0.5554933 0.5902116 1.451594
[4,] 0.8698215 0.8785197 6.516434
```

However, when I calculate the Bayesian standard ellipse areas, the ellipse of species 1 is larger than 2, and species 3 and 4 are roughly the same size:

```
summary(SEA.B[,1])
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
0.4872  0.9157  1.0660  1.1060  1.2540  2.5790
summary(SEA.B[,2])
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
0.5888  0.7875  0.8404  0.8460  0.8985  1.2260
summary(SEA.B[,3])
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
0.4441  0.7835  0.9126  0.9444  1.0680  2.3930
summary(SEA.B[,4])
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
0.6528  0.8674  0.9272  0.9328  0.9922  1.4400

> Pg1.lt.g2 <- sum( SEA.B[,1] < SEA.B[,2] ) / nrow(SEA.B)
> Pg1.lt.g2
[1] 0.1692
> Pg3.lt.g4 <- sum( SEA.B[,3] < SEA.B[,4] ) / nrow(SEA.B)
> Pg3.lt.g4
[1] 0.5244
```

It is not what I would expect at all. But, my sample sizes for species 1 and 3 are much smaller (n=18 each) than 2 and 4 (n=both 104), and I'm wondering if that may have increased uncertainty resulting in a larger estimate?
The data passed the mshapirotest and meets assumptions for multivariate normality. In that case, would comparing the area between species 1 and 2 (and 3 with 4) be futile because of the differences in sample size and uncertainty?

Is it possible to compare difference in ellipse size using SEAc instead of SEA?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the Bayesian standard ellipse area using SEAc instead of SEA to correct for small sample size?

Answer (score 0):

The measures for Standard ellipse area (SEA) and Convex Hull area (TA) are highly influenced by the sample size, and overestimate the area for small samples. This issue is precisely what the bayesian calculation of the ellipse area tries to correct. Take a look at the paper linked below for further clarification!

[Jackson, A. L., Inger, R., Parnell, A. C. and Bearhop, S. (2011), Comparing >>isotopic niche widths among and within communities: SIBER – Stable Isotope >Bayesian Ellipses in R. Journal of Animal Ecology, 80: 595–602. doi: 10.1111/j.1365-2656.2011.01806.x](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/wol1/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2656.2011.01806.x/abstract)